# How to stop vagrant up process from provision

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, vagrant

Is it possible to stop vagrant up process from provision shell script?

I want execute vagrant destroy if the argument of script is wrong.

Example:
It is on vagrant provision file.

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "Some wrong"
    exit;
fi
```

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.path = "vagrantprovision.sh"
    s.args   = ["arg"]
end
```

Comment: Maybe you could use kill -9 pid and get the pid using ps ax | grep "expression". Check out ps ax | grep ruby or ps ax | grep Vagrant to see what exactly expression should look like. OBVIOUSLY, THIS APPLIES IF YOU USE LINUX

Comment: Unfortunately, it will not work because the script runs on the virtual machine and the process of vagrant on the local. From the virtual machine level it does not show vagrant. I looked it up.

Answer (score 1):

Did you not answer the question so created one shell file in which I check everything. If something is wrong I just execute `exit` and `echo the problem`.

but you must know that you must execute `vagrant destroy` on local machine.